# If statement infinite loop

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, if-statement

So my alarm i'm creating uses a animation in it, and I finally go that down and the ability to reset itself. But now ill activate it the first time, then if I input the alarm wake up time again the alarm will go off 2 times, if I input for a 3rd time it does the same thing only this time the alarm goes off 3 times.

Here is the code:

```
    private void dispatcherTimer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh") + ":" + DateTime.Now.ToString("mm") + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("t"+2);
    }

    //ALARM CLOCK

    private void dispatcherTimer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpacityLower.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        OpacityLower.AutoReverse = false;
        OpacityLower.To = 0.0;
        OpacityRaise.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        OpacityRaise.AutoReverse = false;
        OpacityRaise.To = 100.0;

        //Alarm settings

        if (label1.Content.Equals(label2.Content))
        {
            //ANIMATION
            OpacityLower.Completed += (s, d) =>
                {
                    //Actual Wake Up Call, of which i took out so nobody could get the code, also it not relevant to this,

                    TimeOfDayCB.Text = "";
                    HourAlarmCB.Text = "";
                    MinuteAlarmCB.Text = "";
                    label2.Content = null;
                    dispatcherTimer2.Stop();
                    label2.BeginAnimation(Label.OpacityProperty, OpacityRaise);

                    OpacityRaise.Completed += (z, c) =>
                        {
                            TimeOfDayCB.Text = "";
                            HourAlarmCB.Text = "";
                            MinuteAlarmCB.Text = "";
                            label2.Content = null;
                            dispatcherTimer2.Stop();
                        };
                };
            label2.BeginAnimation(Label.OpacityProperty, OpacityLower);
            dispatcherTimer2.Stop();
        }
    }
```

So after seeing my code if you could tell me why this is happening, and please ignore how badly the code is written... (I was doing a testing phase which equals messy coding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end I used this website which helped me finish the code: [When an animation is completed](http://wangmo.wordpress.com/2007/08/07/when-an-animation-is-completed/)

I just switched the event for a story board with my already existing "OpacityRaised" event!

the made a new event to house all the alarm wake up info and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely that you're subscribing to events more than once here:

```
//ANIMATION
OpacityLower.Completed += (s, d) =>
```

..and here:

```
OpacityRaise.Completed += (z, c) =>
```

Every time the timer ticks.. a new event is added to the queue. This is why they are called `MulticastDelegate`s.. they can have more than one (and the reason you use `+=` to append).

Luckily the fix is easy. Your event(s) don't actually rely on any variables/code around it. So take the event subscriptions out of your timer tick so they fire once (at app startup perhaps) and it should be fine*.

<sup>* assuming the rest of your code doesn't do similar stuff.</sup>

Comment: Ya that is where I thought the problem would lie. So to fix that what should I do Opacity.Lowered.Completed += ??? or Opacity.Lowered.Completed; Also the Opacity.Raised event does the samething...

Comment: Move all of them out of the `dispatcherTimer2_Tick` method and into your application startup.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix that. It still fires twice, I think the labels them selves aren't getting reset on the second time through

Comment: Could it be the fact that im not using a story board? I beleive that Completed Event requires one